# Scroll bar appearing even when overflow is set to hidden?

Tags: css, overflow, mobile-website

I'm developing a website, http://m.vancouverislandlife.com/, and when a page is loaded, it's swapped in from the side, just like I want it to. However, when it's swapped in from the right, a scrollbar appears on the bottom. This happened when I switched from swapping the entire body to swapping only a specific element and apparently setting an explicit width and using `overflow: hidden` just isn't working. What am I doing wrong?

(The important script is `swapp.js`. Please visit the website in a WebKit browser.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apply

```
position: fixed;
height: 100%;
width: 100%;
```

to `#content` and that'll fix it.